# MySQL - COUNT with or without an AS, why doesn't this work?

Tags: mysql

Working through SQLZOO and can't figure out why one version of this code runs and why the second doesn't.  Can somebody explain why it is necessary to use the AS actors instead of COUNT(actors.id)?  Thanks for the explanation!

**Working:**

```
SELECT title, COUNT(actor.id) AS actors FROM actor
        JOIN casting ON casting.actorid=actor.id
        JOIN movie ON movie.id=casting.movieid
WHERE yr=1978
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY actors DESC
```

**Not working:**

```
SELECT title, COUNT(actor.id) FROM actor
        JOIN casting ON casting.actorid=actor.id
        JOIN movie ON movie.id=casting.movieid
WHERE yr=1978
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY COUNT(actor.id) DESC
```

Comment: Does ```ORDER BY `COUNT(actor.id)` DESC``` work in the second example?

Comment: There's no reason why this wouldn't work. What's not working? Any errors popping?

Comment: Just tried it again so I must have missed something because it ran, but the order is different than when I use AS actors.  SQLZOO requires it to be exactly the same.  For some reason the order of the titles changes when the count is the same.

Comment: The ordering of items that have the same count is undefined until you give it a second item to order by

Comment: @Dezza - but to clarify what he means by 'undefined' - really 'random'. MySQL will do different things on different runs, no guarantees. As he says, create another rule (e.g. Order By Count(actor.id) desc, actor.id asc.

Comment: Ahh, perfect.  Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Both solutions are work. You just need one more condition to get the correct answer in SQLZoo. Because the criteria requires you to `order by` the number of actors and then title. So you just need to add `title` to your order by clause as following:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(actor.id) FROM actor
    JOIN casting ON casting.actorid=actor.id
    JOIN movie ON movie.id=casting.movieid
WHERE yr=1978
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY COUNT(actor.id) DESC, title
```